# add a constraint or a trigger to verify value before insert or update for SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables : parent and child, there is a certain column in the parent table defining max_bill_value, and a column in child table defining bill_value.
the condition here is :

```
sum(bill_value)<max_bill_value
```

the trigger body will be something like this

```
SELECT bill_value INTO max_bill_value FROM parent_table WHERE id=:NEW.parent_id; 

SELECT SUM(bill_value) INTO sum_bill_value FROM child_table where parent_id=:NEW.parent_id; 

if max_bill_value < sum_bill_value then raise_application_error(-20001, 'ERROR!!!');
end if;
```

my first solution was the use of a trigger, which was impossible because of the

> "ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it."  message.

so what would be a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using a *row level trigger*. Convert it to a *statement level trigger* starting by removing the piece `FOR EACH ROW` in order to prevent getting a *mutating table* error such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_chk_bill
BEFORE INSERT ON child_table
--FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  sum_bill_value child_table.bill_value%TYPE;
  max_bill_value parent_table.bill_value%TYPE; 
BEGIN
  SELECT bill_value
    INTO max_bill_value  
    FROM parent_table;

  SELECT SUM(bill_value)
    INTO sum_bill_value  
    FROM child_table;
    
  IF sum_bill_value > max_bill_value THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20333,'MaX bill value is exceeded'); 
  END IF;  
        
END;
/
```

Comment: that might probably work except i need to reference :OLD and :NEW, since i'm going to get the values of  sum_bill_value and max_bill_value like this:
```
 SELECT bill_value
    INTO max_bill_value  
    FROM parent_table
WHERE id=:NEW.parent_id;
```
and 
```
 SELECT SUM(bill_value)
    INTO sum_bill_value  
    FROM child_table
where parent_id=:NEW.parent_id;
```
i can't reference OLD and NEW in a table level trigger apparently